# Problem identifying which page/page/function locks whole IIS server

Tags: iis, application, pool

I have problem identifying which page/page/function locks whole IIS server.

Out of the blue whole w3wp.exe jumps to CPU 90-98% usage. I have created 3 different application pools to see which w3wp.exe service locks the processor but I am unable to find out this information.

I can only see that 2 of 3 services have 0-5% usage and one is jumping around 90-98% after some while. I think some process/function/redirect/sql is doing this but I would like to eliminate it. So far I am not even able to find the source of the problem. On my local development machine with VS2010 everything works like charm and I am unable to replicate problem.

The server is windows 2k3 web server, sql server 2k5 and .net 4.0

Thank you for your help, links or any information on this issue.

Fero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created 3 different application pools to see which w3wp.exe service locks the processor but I am unable to find out this information.

What do you mean by this? Once you've done this, you can find out which PID (process ID) is taking all your CPU. Then, using something like SysInternals Process Explorer, you can see which application pool is associated with which PID.

/edit - Doing this on one of my machines, I see that I have multiple instances of w3wp.exe running under svchost.exe - when I check the svchost.exe properties, under Image, I see a command line of

`C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k iissvcs`

so I know I'm looking at IIS. If I view the command line for one of the w3wp.exe processes, I see

`c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -a \\.\pipe\iisipm58b150c3-732e-4bd0-a8ef-f5544c062674 -t 20 -ap "DemoPool"`

- the last parameter is the name of my application pool.

Once you've narrowed it down to which application pool, you've got to apply what you know about what's running in your application pool to figure it out. Put some debugging in, tail a log, I don't know. If you're still stuck at that point, you should probably throw the question over to StackOverflow.

Comment: When I check Task Manager and Processes there is only image name, user name, cpu % and mem usage. No PID for me.

Comment: 1. If you just use Process Explorer, that will tell you everything

2. In the builtin Task Manager, if you go to View... Select Columns, you can choose the PID.